# Magento OPC Continue button not working

Tags: java, php, ajax, debugging, magento

I've just started skinning the checkout area of what was a fresh install of magento 1.7.

Upon finishing the billing/login area, I was attempting to move onto shipping address, seems the continue button does not work to save the info.

firefox console is reporting the following error on opcheckout.js (line 92)

```
container is null
[Break On This Error]   

container.addClassName('disabled');
```

chrome console reports the following error on the same line

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'addClassName' of null /skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:92
Checkout.setLoadWaiting /skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:92
Billing.save /skin/frontend/base/default/js/opcheckout.js:307
onclick
```

In regards to changes to the form, except for adding a new div inside a few of the li's and removing the company field I've made no changes to the billing.phtml (posted below)

```
<form id="co-billing-form" action="">
<fieldset>
    <ul class="form-list">
    <?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?>
        <li class="wide">
            <label for="billing-address-select"><?php echo $this->__('Select a billing address from your address book or enter a new address.') ?></label>
            <div class="input-box">
                <?php echo $this->getAddressesHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
            </div>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <li id="billing-new-address-form"<?php if ($this->customerHasAddresses()): ?> style="display:none;"<?php endif; ?>>
        <fieldset>
            <input type="hidden" name="billing[address_id]" value="<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getId() ?>" id="billing:address_id" />
            <ul>
                <li class="fields"><?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_name')->setObject($this->getAddress()->getFirstname() ? $this->getAddress() : $this->getQuote()->getCustomer())->setForceUseCustomerRequiredAttributes(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?></li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <!--<div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:company"><?php echo $this->__('Company') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCompany()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Company') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('company') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
                    <!--<input type="hidden" id="billing:company" name="billing[company]" value="none"/>-->

        <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>
        <div class="fullfield">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:email" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[email]" id="billing:email" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getEmail()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Email Address') ?>" class="input-text validate-email required-entry" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
                <li class="wide">
                <div class="fullfield">
                    <label for="billing:street1" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Address') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address') ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street1" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet(1)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
        <?php $_streetValidationClass = trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)); ?>
        <?php for ($_i = 2, $_n = $this->helper('customer/address')->getStreetLines(); $_i <= $_n; $_i++): ?>
                <li class="wide">
                <div class="fullfield">
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Street Address %s', $_i) ?>" name="billing[street][]" id="billing:street<?php echo $_i ?>" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getStreet($_i)) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $_streetValidationClass ?>" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                </li>
        <?php endfor; ?>
                <?php if ($this->helper('customer/address')->isVatAttributeVisible()) : ?>
                <li class="wide">
                    <label for="billing:vat_id"><?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?></label>
                    <div class="input-box">
                        <input type="text" id="billing:vat_id" name="billing[vat_id]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('VAT Number') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('vat_id') ?>" />
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:city" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('City') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('City') ?>" name="billing[city]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('city') ?>" id="billing:city" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:region_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('County') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <select id="billing:region_id" name="billing[region_id]" title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="validate-select" style="display:none;">
                                <option value=""><?php echo $this->__('Please select County, State or Region') ?></option>
                            </select>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                            //<![CDATA[
                                $('billing:region_id').setAttribute('defaultValue',  "<?php echo $this->getAddress()->getRegionId() ?>");
                            //]]>
                            </script>
                            <input type="text" id="billing:region" name="billing[region]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getRegion()) ?>"  title="<?php echo $this->__('State/Province') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('region') ?>" style="display:none;" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:postcode" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Postcode') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" title="<?php echo $this->__('Zip/Postal Code') ?>" name="billing[postcode]" id="billing:postcode" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>" class="input-text validate-zip-international <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('postcode') ?>" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:country_id" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Country') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <?php echo $this->getCountryHtmlSelect('billing') ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="fields">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:telephone" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="text" name="billing[telephone]" value="<?php echo $this->escapeHtml($this->getAddress()->getTelephone()) ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Telephone') ?>" class="input-text <?php echo $this->helper('customer/address')->getAttributeValidationClass('telephone') ?>" id="billing:telephone" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </li>
                <?php if(!$this->isCustomerLoggedIn()): ?>

        <?php $_dob = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_dob') ?>
        <?php $_gender = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('customer/widget_gender') ?>
            <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled() || $_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                <li class="fields">
                <?php if ($_dob->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_dob->setDate($this->getQuote()->getCustomerDob())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($_gender->isEnabled()): ?>
                    <div class="field">
                        <?php echo $_gender->setGender($this->getQuote()->getCustomerGender())->setFieldIdFormat('billing:%s')->setFieldNameFormat('billing[%s]')->toHtml() ?>
                    </div>
                <?php endif ?>
                </li>
            <?php endif ?>

            <?php if ($this->isTaxvatEnabled()):?>
                <li><?php echo $this->getTaxvatHtml() ?></li>
            <?php endif; ?>

                <li class="fields" id="register-customer-password">
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:customer_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[customer_password]" id="billing:customer_password" title="<?php echo $this->__('Password') ?>" class="input-text required-entry validate-password" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="field">
                        <label for="billing:confirm_password" class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?></label>
                        <div class="input-box">
                            <input type="password" name="billing[confirm_password]" title="<?php echo $this->__('Confirm Password') ?>" id="billing:confirm_password" class="input-text required-entry validate-cpassword" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me'); ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php if ($this->isCustomerLoggedIn() && $this->customerHasAddresses()):?>
                    <li class="control">
                        <input type="checkbox" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" title="<?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?>" id="billing:save_in_address_book" onchange="if(window.shipping) shipping.setSameAsBilling(false);"<?php if ($this->getAddress()->getSaveInAddressBook()):?> checked="checked"<?php endif;?> class="checkbox" /><label for="billing:save_in_address_book"><?php echo $this->__('Save in address book') ?></label>
                    </li>
                <?php else:?>
                    <li class="no-display"><input type="hidden" name="billing[save_in_address_book]" value="1" /></li>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('form.additional.info'); ?>
            </ul>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('persistent.remember.me.tooltip'); ?>
        </fieldset>
     </li>
    <?php if ($this->canShip()): ?>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_yes" value="1"<?php if ($this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo  $this->__('Deliver to this address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = true;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_yes"><?php echo  $this->__('Deliver to this address') ?></label></li>
        <li class="control">
            <input type="radio" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" id="billing:use_for_shipping_no" value="0"<?php if (!$this->isUseBillingAddressForShipping()) {?> checked="checked"<?php }?> title="<?php echo $this->__('Deliver to different address') ?>" onclick="$('shipping:same_as_billing').checked = false;" class="radio" /><label for="billing:use_for_shipping_no"><?php echo $this->__('Deliver to different address') ?></label>
        </li>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php if (!$this->canShip()): ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="billing[use_for_shipping]" value="1" />
    <?php endif; ?>


        <p class="required pink fleft" style="margin-top:20px;"><?php echo $this->__('* Required Fields') ?></p>
        <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('CONTINUE') ?>" class="pinkbuttonopc fright" onclick="billing.save()"><span><?php echo $this->__('CONTINUE') ?></span></button>
        <span class="please-wait" id="billing-please-wait" style="display:none;">
            <img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/opc-ajax-loader.gif') ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>" class="v-middle" /> <?php echo $this->__('Loading next step...') ?>
        </span>


</fieldset>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
    var billing = new Billing('co-billing-form', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/getAddress') ?>address/', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('checkout/onepage/saveBilling') ?>');
    var billingForm = new VarienForm('co-billing-form');

    //billingForm.setElementsRelation('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', '<?php echo $this->getUrl('directory/json/childRegion') ?>', '<?php echo $this->__('Select State/Province...') ?>');
    $('billing-address-select') && billing.newAddress(!$('billing-address-select').value);

    var billingRegionUpdater = new RegionUpdater('billing:country_id', 'billing:region', 'billing:region_id', <?php echo $this->helper('directory')->getRegionJson() ?>, undefined, 'billing:postcode');
    if ($('onepage-guest-register-button')) {
        Event.observe($('onepage-guest-register-button'), 'click', function(event) {
            var billingRememberMe = $('co-billing-form').select('#remember-me-box');
            if (billingRememberMe.length > 0) {
                if ($('login:guest') && $('login:guest').checked) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].hide();
                } else if ($('login:register') && ($('login:register').checked || $('login:register').type == 'hidden')) {
                    billingRememberMe[0].show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
//]]>
</script>
```

I'm not familiar enough with ajax and the workings of the opc to debug this message. if anyone could be of assistance it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you removed the following container which is required:

```
<div class="buttons-set" id="billing-buttons-container"> .. </div>
```

Comment: I can confirm the checkout steps and their containing OL is completely intact

Comment: Thanks Tim, it's amazing the little silly things you miss after you've done them a hundred times!